# An element of order 5 whose powers are conjugate

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Find a finite group G such that it contains an element g of order 5 and its power $g, g^2, g^3, g^4$ are conjugate elements.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried? As a hint, symmetric groups are always a good place to start....

Comment: Hmm I didn't notice the symmetric group. So far I've tried some small groups of order 10, 15, 20, 25, etc. but none of them works (dihedral group D5 is not valid, group of order 15 is abelian, haven't checked carefully 20 and 25 but they don't seem right)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: in a symmetric group, conjugacy class is determined by cycle type. What is the conjugacy class of $g^2$ where $g$ is a 5-cycle?

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed.